# instantiate global variables in parallel way within WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, mvvm-light

In my WPF application , the instantiation of the viewmodel classes takes a lot of time, so I think, to solve this issue, to create a static objects when I launch my application :

```
 protected override  void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        ViewModelLocator locator = (ViewModelLocator)App.Current.Resources["Locator"];
        LoginWindowViewModel.objFicheViewModel = locator.FicheViewModel;
        LoginWindowViewModel.objFormationsViewModel = locator.FormationsViewModel;
        LoginWindowViewModel.objFacturationViewModel = locator.FacturationViewModel;
        LoginWindowViewModel.objGestionDPCViewModel = locator.GestionDPCViewModel;
        LoginWindowViewModel.objGestionGDPViewModel = locator.GestionGDPViewModel;

    }
```

So I need to know :

1. Is it a good solution?
2. How to improve it to make the instantiation work in a parallel way to avoid UI pause( the instantiation part takes 5 seconds!!)

Comment: A ViewModel is *not* supposed to take a long time to instantiate - it corresponds to a single screenful of data, not to the screen itself. It's the equivalent of a DTO for your View. It *can't* be converted to a global object unless your data is static/read-only in the first place. You should investigate the performance issues, not try to hide them behind a global object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `async` and `await` to set up your ViewModels.

Consider this:

Create a property called **IsSettingUp** in your `LoginWindowViewModel`, like so:

```
private bool _IsSettingUp;

    public bool IsSettingUp
    {
        get { return _IsSettingUp; }
        set 
        { 
            _IsSettingUp = value;

            //On property changed stuff
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Then create an `async` method responsible for creating your ViewModels.

```
public async void Setup()
    {
        this.IsSettingUp = true;

        await SetupViewModels();

        //Other initialization stuff here if needed

        this.IsSettingUp = false;
    }
```

And the **SetupViewModels** method would look something like this:

```
private async Task SetupViewModels()
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ViewModelLocator locator = (ViewModelLocator)App.Current.Resources["Locator"];
            LoginWindowViewModel.objFicheViewModel = locator.FicheViewModel;
            LoginWindowViewModel.objFormationsViewModel = locator.FormationsViewModel;
            LoginWindowViewModel.objFacturationViewModel = locator.FacturationViewModel;
            LoginWindowViewModel.objGestionDPCViewModel = locator.GestionDPCViewModel;
            LoginWindowViewModel.objGestionGDPViewModel = locator.GestionGDPViewModel;
        });
    }
```

To make use of the **IsSettingUp** property, consider creating a control that will be visible if **IsSettingUp** is true. Perhaps a loading icon, or a screen overlay. This will ensure that the UI will remain responsive while your ViewModels are being created.

Comment: `async void` is *only* meant for event handlers, never for asynchronous execution of methods. Moreover, there is no point in using `async/await` in a method that simply runs a task and gets awaited by another method - just return the Task.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you suggest as an improvement of this  solution

Comment: I have `TargetInvocationException` in the task `SetupViewModels`

Comment: @LamloumiAfif find out why the ViewModels take a long time to initialize. *Don't* try to load all data at the start, just put enough data for an initial display. Load the rest asynchronoulsy,eg as shown [here](http://blog.giovannimodica.com/post/a-sample-cross-platform-application-using-mvvm). The INotifyPropertyChanged events and DataBinding will take care of updating the View when the underlying data changes in the ViewModel